# Bound component value isn't updating

Tags: ember.js

I have this component:

```
App.AppTestComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'input',
  type: 'text',
  value: undefined,
  attributeBindings: ['type', 'value'],
  
  valueObserver: function() {
    console.log('This code is never triggered');
  }.observes('value')
});
```

I bind the value attribute using the `attributeBinding`, but when I change the `textbox` value, the value property isn't updating, and the `valueObserver` isn't triggered.

How do I bind to the value attribute of a input `type="text"` ? Do I have to extend from `Ember.TextField` ?

Here's an example of the problem: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/lodisucasa/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was digging in the Ember code to see how it works for the `Ember.TextField` component (see [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-views/lib/views/text_field.js)).

I didn't see anything specific in there, but I noticed the component is using `TextSupport` mixin (see [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-views/lib/views/text_field.js#L26)).

If you look at `TextSupport` mixin ([here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-views/lib/mixins/text_support.js)), you will see that it listens for `input` events and then responds to those events by actively setting the `value` property inside `_elementValueDidChange` method:

`this.on("input", this, this._elementValueDidChange);`

So... if you want your component to have the same functionality, you need to do the following:

```
App.AppTestComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'input',
  type: 'text',
  value: "",
  attributeBindings: ['type', 'value'],

  init: function() {
    this._super.apply(this, arguments);
    this.on("input", this, this._elementValueDidChange);
  },

  _elementValueDidChange: function() {
    Ember.set(this, 'value', this.$().val());
  },

  valueObserver: function() {
    console.log('This code is never triggered');
  }.observes('value')
});
```

Working example [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/teqilu/2/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: I know that extending from Ember.TextField is working (like I wrote above), but why do I have to extend from Ember.TextField and not just bind to the value attribute?

Comment: Disregard my previous answer and see the updated version